# RocksDB iterate in lexicographic order

Tags: rocksdb

Does RocksDB guarantee retrieval of keys in lexicographic order when using the default comparator?
And what if data is divided into multiple SST files, does it still retrieve it in the correct order?

I did try a simple expirement with a small set of data and it worked as expected. However, i dont know if it still works when i have terrabytes of data and many sst files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is guaranteed in all situations

Comment: Good to know - thank you. Do you have any citations or supporting evidence we can refer to?

Comment: Rocksdb is an *ordered* kv store. Sst means sorted strings table. There is no 'citation' since it is obvious. But nonetheless https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/include/rocksdb/options.h#L113